# Blowfish ECB Mode in BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle, mode, ecb

This thread should not be for discussion on how bad ECB mode is, and that I should change it, but that BouncyCastle doesn't really support the mode, except for in Java, where you can use "getInstance". The code I am using is this, and it only decrypts the first block(0x1000 bytes) correctly.

```
BufferedBlockCipher Blowfish = new BufferedBlockCipher(new BlowfishEngine());
KeyParameter r3 = new KeyParameter(Blowfish_Key);
Blowfish.Init(false, r3);
Blowfish.ProcessBytes(pio.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)pio.Length, output, 0);
```

I guess the question here would be, is there a way to use ECB mode with the library, or are there any other classes I could use?

Comment: A block should not be 0x1000 bytes, it is 8 to 32 bytes for symmetric encryption, above code should work, I think the error is elsewhere.

Comment: You are using ECB mode in your example. What makes you believe otherwise?

Comment: That it is not decrypting the other bytes. I used another program that used a different class and it worked. I figured out it was working in 8 bytes, so I guess that it is another problem. I'll keep trying other things.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. My file was probably corrupt, since I downloaded it again and it worked successfully.